# How to use awk and grep combination

Tags: awk

I have a file with 10 columns and lots of lines. I want to add a fix correction to the 10th column where its line contain 'G01' pattern.

For example, in the file below

```
AS G17  2014  3 31  0  2  0.000000  1   -0.809159910000E-04                     
AS G12  2014  3 31  0  2  0.000000  1    0.195515363000E-03                     
AS G15  2014  3 31  0  2  0.000000  1   -0.171167837000E-03                     
AS G29  2014  3 31  0  2  0.000000  1    0.521982134000E-03                     
AS G07  2014  3 31  0  2  0.000000  1    0.329889640000E-03                     
AS G05  2014  3 31  0  2  0.000000  1   -0.381588767000E-03                     
AS G25  2014  3 31  0  2  0.000000  1    0.203352860000E-04                     
AS G01  2014  3 31  0  2  0.000000  1    0.650180300000E-05                     
AS G24  2014  3 31  0  2  0.000000  1   -0.258444780000E-04                     
AS G27  2014  3 31  0  2  0.000000  1   -0.203691700000E-04
```

the 10th column of the line with G01 should be corrected.
I've used 'awk' with 'while' loop to do that, but it takes a very long time for massive files.
It will be appreciated if anybody can help for a more effective way.

Comment: `awk '/G01/{$10=NEW_VALUE}1' file` will do what you want

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk since awk can do anything useful that grep can do and there is no reason for a `while` loop (inside or outside of awk) to do what you want.

Comment: If the *"correction"* you wish to add is 100, you could use `awk '/G01/{$10+=100} 1' yourFile`

Comment: It works but with some problem in reducing the decimal places of the final result. Do you have any idea for setting the decimal places beforehand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
awk '$2 == "G01" {$10="value"}1' file.txt
```

To preserve whitespaces you can use the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20836890/2614364) :

```
awk '$2 == "G01" {
    data=1
    n=split($0,a," ",b)
    a[10]="value"
    line=b[0]
    for (i=1;i<=n; i++){
        line=(line a[i] b[i])
    }
    print line
}{
    if (data!=1){
        print;
    }
    else {
        data=0;
    }
}' file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It works well, but after adding the correction, the resulted column 10th has reduced decimal places than the original one. It would be great if there would be a way to keep the decimal places fixed.

Comment: See my updated answer, you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20836890/2614364)

Answer (score 1):

> the 10th column of the line with G01 should be corrected

Syntax is as follows, which will search for regex given inside `/../` in current record/line/row regardless of which field the regex was found

## Either

```
$ awk '/regex/{ $10 = "somevalue"; print }' infile
```

## OR

`1` at the end does default operation `print $0`, that is print current record/line/row

```
$ awk '/regex/{ $10 = "somevalue" }1' infile
```

## OR

`$0` means current record/line/row

```
$ awk '$0 ~ /regex/{ $10 = "somevalue"}1' infile
```

## So in current context, it will be any of the following

```
$ awk '/G01/{$10 = "somevalue" ; print }' infile

$ awk '/G01/{$10 = "somevalue" }1' infile

$ awk '$0 ~ /G01/{$10 = "somevalue"; print }' infile

$ awk '$0 ~ /G01/{$10 = "somevalue" }1' infile
```

## If you would like to strict your search to specific field/column in record/line/row then

`$10` means 10th field/column

```
$ awk '$2 == "G01" {$10 = "somevalue"; print }' infile

$ awk '$2 == "G01" {$10 = "somevalue" }1' infile
```

In case if you would like to pass say some word from shell variable to awk or just a word then

```
$ awk -v search="G01" -v replace="foo" '$2 == search {$10 = replace }1' infile
```

and then same from shell

```
$ search_value="G01"
$ new_value="foo"
$ awk -v search="$search_value" -v replace="$new_value" '$2 == search {$10 = replace }1' infile
```

**From man**

```
-v var=val

   --assign var=val

    Assign  the  value  val to the variable var, before execution of
    the program begins.  Such variable values are available  to  the
    BEGIN block of an AWK program.
```

## For additional syntax instructions:

> **"sed & awk" by Dale Dougherty and Arnold Robbins
>
>   (O'Reilly)**
>
> **"UNIX Text Processing," by Dale Dougherty and Tim O'Reilly (Hayden
>   Books)**
>
> **"GAWK: Effective awk Programming," by Arnold D. Robbins
>
>   (O'Reilly)**
>
> **http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/**

Comment: Thanks for the documentation and formatting effort.

Comment: @ychaouche you're welcome