# replacing string in specific column and range of lines while preserving whitespaces

Tags: awk, sed

I am wondering if there is a simple way using sed or awk to replace a string in a specific column and in multiple lines with another string. The string repeats in other columns but I would like the string in a specific column to be replaced while preserving the inconsistent number of white spaces between columns. For example, I'm hoping to replace 'A' in column 3, lines 2-4 to 'B', while preserving the same whitespaces between columns.

```
 1  2      A     4    A     B       C         A  E    F  G   7  8    9 
 2  11     A     4    A     B       C         A  E    F  G   7  8    9 
 3  12     A     4    A     B       C         A  E    F  G   7  8    9 
 4  13     A     4    A     B       C         A  E    F  G   7  8    9 
 5  14     A     4    A     B       C         A  E    F  G   7  8    9 
 6  15     A     4    A     B       C         A  E    F  G   7  8    9
 .
 .
```

to

```
 1  2      A     4    A     B       C         A  E    F  G   7  8    9 
 2  11     B     4    A     B       C         A  E    F  G   7  8    9 
 3  12     B     4    A     B       C         A  E    F  G   7  8    9 
 4  13     B     4    A     B       C         A  E    F  G   7  8    9 
 5  14     A     4    A     B       C         A  E    F  G   7  8    9 
 6  15     A     4    A     B       C         A  E    F  G   7  8    9
 .
 .
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the condition for the line range, before the action you have to do, `NR` is the record number, usually the line number.

```
awk 'NR>=2 && NR<=4{sub("A","B",$3)} 1' file
1 2 A 3
2 3 B 4
3 4 B 5
4 5 B 6
5 6 A 7
```

`1` at the end means to do the default action, which is to `print` every line. Also `sub` is one of the [GNU Awk string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).

---

**UPDATE**

For your updated requirements, doing the replacement on `$0` without splitting to fields, will work. Also this `sub` replaces only the first occurenc of `A` in line.

```
awk 'NR>=2 && NR<=4{sub("A","B",$0)} 1' file
```

Comment: thanks! and I am wondering what the number 1 represents at the end of the quotations?

Comment: Thanks! and is there something that I could add to preserve the spaces between columns? If the columns are separated by two spaces, it seems that the command would change it to one.

Comment: Thanks! If the whitespaces between each column is not fixed, so there are 2 spaces for some, 3 spaces for some, etc, is there a simple command for it?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is another way, for example, instead of identifying the string A in the 3rd column, is there a way to identify A by assigning it as the 5th element from the left (including whitespaces) and solely replacing it.

Comment: There are many ways, it depends on the input file. If you have a specific case you want to preserve whitespaces in output, while replacing a column, I suggest posting a new question with a representative example input, you will get answers with different ways to do it.

Comment: Also, this is a helpful read for preserving spaces: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835437/how-to-preserve-the-original-whitespace-between-fields-in-awk

Comment: Thanks! I've edited the question, sorry about the earlier confusion