# Awk command to set variable name while matching a regular expression

Tags: bash, awk, grep, cut, ncbi

I have a names.dmp file which contains taxonomy ids and scientific names among other details.

I want to fetch the scientific name of a particular tax-id, for which I am running this command:

`cat names.dmp | grep "scientific name" | awk '$1~/^10090$/{print $0}' | cut -d "|" -f1,2`

which gives me the output:

> `10090    |   Mus musculus`

But I need this to be dynamic, i.e., set a variable `id=10090` and use this variable inside the regular expression. I need an exact match of the value while using "id", as there are entries such as 210090 and 100904 which I am getting as output which are not needed.

I am quite inexperienced when it comes to awk, so any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is the example input:

```
10089   |       Mus formosanus Kuroda, 1925     |               |       authority       |
10089   |       Mus formosanus  |               |       synonym |
10089   |       ricefield mouse |               |       common name     |
10089   |       Ryukyu mouse    |               |       genbank common name     |
10090   |       house mouse     |               |       genbank common name     |
10090   |       LK3 transgenic mice     |               |       includes        |
10090   |       mouse   |       mouse <Mus musculus>    |       common name     |
10090   |       Mus musculus Linnaeus, 1758     |               |       authority       |
10090   |       Mus musculus    |               |       scientific name |
10090   |       Mus sp. 129SV   |               |       includes        |
10090   |       nude mice       |               |       includes        |
10090   |       transgenic mice |               |       includes        |
10091   |       Mus castaneus   |               |       synonym |
10091   |       Mus musculus castaneus  |               |       scientific name |
10091   |       Mus musculus castaneus Waterhouse, 1843 |               |       authority       |
10091   |       southeastern Asian house mouse  |               |       genbank common name     |
10092   |       Mus domesticus  |               |       synonym |
10092   |       Mus musculus domesticus Schwarz & Scharz 1943   |               |       authority       |
10092   |       Mus musculus domesticus |               |       scientific name |
10092   |       Mus musculus praetextus |               |       synonym |
100902  |       Fusarium oxysporum f. sp. conglutinans  |               |       scientific name |
100903  |       Fusarium oxysporum f. sp. fragariae     |               |       scientific name |
100905  |       Cloning vector pACN     |               |       scientific name |
100906  |       Nitrosomonas sp. ENI-11 |               |       scientific name |
100907  |       Chilean sea bass        |               |       common name     |
```

And the output I need is:

`10090 | Mus musculus`

Comment: You don't need a separate grep command. Use awk for the search too.

Comment: Have you looked at our answers telling you how to pass a bash variable into awk?

Comment: If you could post a sample input and desired output, then that would be great.

Comment: For the exact match, just use `==` not `~` or the implicit `/` behavior.

Comment: And as Jetchisel says, to test our answers we need sample input.

Comment: @JetI have added the example input and desired output.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I did try this:

`cat names.dmp | grep "scientific name" | awk pattern=$id '$1==pattern' | cut -d "|" -f1,2`

Got this:
awk: fatal: cannot open file `$1==pattern' for reading (No such file or directory)

Comment: As our answers say, it's `awk -v "pattern=$id"` -- you can't leave out the `-v`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `awk`, frequently, you don't need anything else:

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]]*\\|[[:space:]]*' -v id="10090" '
  /scientific name/ && $1 == id {print $1 " | " $2}' file
10090 | Mus musculus
```

1. `-F'[[:space:]]*\\|[[:space:]]*'`: set the input field separator as space-surrounded `|`.
2. `-v id="10090"`: declare `awk` variable `id` and assign it `10090` (change this if needed).
3. If the input record matches string `scientific name` and the first field equals `id`, print the two first fields separated by `|`.

As noted in comments this does not preserve the input field separators. In case you want to preserve them you can use the `split` function of GNU `awk`, instead of the input field separator, to save the fields in an array and the separators in another:

```
$ awk -v id="10090" '/scientific name/ {
    split($0,f,/[[:space:]]*\|[[:space:]]*/,s)
    if(f[1] == id) print f[1] s[1] f[2]}' file
10090   |       Mus musculus
```

Finally, if your `awk` is not GNU `awk` but you want to preserve the field separators, you can use `match` and `substr` instead of `split`:

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]]*\\|[[:space:]]*' -v id="10090" '
  /scientific name/ && $1==id {
    a=match($0,/\|/); b=match(substr($0,a+1),/[[:space:]]*\|/)
    print substr($0,1,a+b-1)}' file
10090   |       Mus musculus
```

We simply use `match` to find the index of the first `|` (`a`), then the index of the first space before the second `|` (`b`), and print only the everything before that (`substr`).

Comment: It works.

I had tried this

`echo $(cat names.dmp | grep "scientific name" | awk -v pattern=$id '$1==pattern' | cut -d "|" -f1,2 )`

But yours is obviously a much better way. Thanks a lot

Comment: @chan-98 this doesn't produce the output you desire, does it? according to your question, it should be `10090    |   Mus musculus`

Comment: @Paolo Good point. I added another solution that preserves the input separators, in case it matters.

Comment: The new solution produced a different, incorrect output `10090   |       Mus musculus`

Comment: Even though it seems like now OP has changed the desired output in the question, so whatever

Comment: When you find you need to double escapes, e.g. `\\|`, consider using a bracket expression instead, `[|]` for slightly improved clarity. It's obvious at a glance that `[|]` means a literal `|` but you have to consider context and think about it to understand whether `\\|` is a literal `|` or a literal ```\``` followed by a regexp "or" metachar `|`.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be:

```
id=10090
awk -v id="$id" '/scientific name/ && $1 == id' names.dmp | cut -d "|" -f1,2
```

You can also preserve whitespace in awk (using e.g. [How to preserve the original whitespace between fields in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20835437/12957340)) and incorporate the `cut` command into your awk command, but as you describe yourself as 'inexperienced', this is probably the best solution.

Comment: Yes I managed to try this as well:

`echo $(cat names.dmp | grep "scientific name" | awk -v pattern=$id '$1==pattern' | cut -d "|" -f1,2 )`

It works.
 thank you.

Comment: @chan-98 not `-v pattern=$id` but `-v pattern="$id"`. Always quote your shell variables unless you have a specific reason to remove the quotes. Also, you don't need `cut` when you're using awk.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```bash
$ id=10090
$ awk -v id="$id" 'BEGIN{FS="| +";OFS="    |   "} /scientific name/ && $1==id {print $1,$3" "$4}' file
10090    |   Mus musculus
```

Answer (score 0):

While you **can** set awk variables from the outside and that this is usually the best solution, your specific case is so simple that interpolation by the shell works as well:

```
awk '$1~/^'$id'$/{print $0}'
```

Since you know that your `id` is always a string of digits, you don't even have to double-quote here.

Comment: Oh I was trying this without surrounding $id with quotes. Thank you so much

Comment: @chan-98 : You don' surround `id` with quotes. You need the part to the left of $id to be quoted to avoid expansion of $1, and the part to the right to avoid word splitting and expansion of $0 and $/. You could have it also written completely unquoted as `awk \$1~/^$id\$/{print\ \$0}`

Comment: That can lead to cryptic failures if `id` ever contains some unexpected value as it's contents become part of the script before awk sees it and is creating a malware injection weakness and can cause yet other failures if `$i` contains yet other values as you're exposing it unquoted to the shell and so asking the shell to perform globbing, word splitting, and filename expansion on it before awk sees it, and it's treating the contents of $i as a regexp and so can have yet more failure cases with unexpected chars in it such as a `.`.

Comment: So don't do that, instead just set an awk variable and do a string comparison - `awk -v id="$id" '$1 == id'`. See [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for more info. And don't write `awk \$1~/^$id\$/{print\ \$0}` - always quote strings (including scripts) in shell unless you have a very specific need to remove the quotes.

Comment: Yes you could say that because the OP shows a presumably hard-coded `id=10090` as their starting point that we could write the code as `awk '$1~/^'$id'$/'` but there's just no point getting into the habit of sometimes doing that vs always (unless you have a specific reason not to) using the far more generally robust `awk -v id="$id" '$1==id'` which is just a handful of characters longer and would continue to work if the OPs real code now or in future doesn't  actually hard-code `id` but gets it from user input, for example.