# Separating columns in Awk (Windows)

Tags: awk

A script retrieves filenames from a server, and includes this line (using windows AWK that comes packaged with msys64):

```
dir "//<server name/dir>" | awk "/DIR/ $6 > 1 {$1=$2=$3=$4=NULL; print $0}" > .\jobList.txt
```

It has recently come to our attention `$0` treats the rest of the line as separate fields, i.e., if there's a double space in the filename, it gets reduced to a single space, which is a problem. However, if we eliminate the ignore columns, as in:

```
dir "//<server name/dir>" | awk "/DIR/ $6 > 1 {print $0}" > .\jobList.txt
```

`$0` is now treated as one long field, and the double spaces are preserved. It's an easy fix after the fact, but is that normal AWK behavior?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include an example of the data being processed showing the position of the filename, what the other columns contain, and what output is desired.

Comment: this is normal behavior; `awk` uses the default field delimiter (multiple/consecutive white spaces) to parse the line into fields; when putting back together as a 'line' (as in this case) the default output field delimiter (single space) is used; to maintain input spacing (eg, consecutive spaces and/or tabs) you typically need to do more work; a web search on `awk maintain spacing` should bring up several hits, eg, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835437), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239218) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253521)

Comment: this is normal: `echo 'a  b  c' | awk '{print "["$0"]"; $1=$1; print "["$0"]"}'`. assigning to a field causes $0 to be recomputed with `FS` replaced by `OFS` (although I can't currently see where this is specified by [the standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_03) which only seems to mention assigning to non-existent fields

Comment: @jhnc "setting any other field causes the re-evaluation of $0" but that isn't totally clear and doesn't mention OFS either.